# Exporting, archiving, or saving ExactTarget mails

Tags: email, html-email, exacttarget

To preface this I'm not an ExactTarget expert.... We use ExactTarget and are interested in more archiving our email newsletters so that our subscribers can later use our articles as a reference. We have an archive folder set up in the exact target system, but that is not customer-facing and contains things like extra code.

As I understand it, the current process for archiving involves taking screenshots of the email that is sent out which is stitched together as a PDF. The PDF's are then stuck behind a password protected folder on a website.

Obviously, this is a hacky/low-tech way to do this.

Are there any ways to export these mails for archival purposes that people are using?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing from the above that you are using the premade templates and creating content using the Exact Target WYSIWYG editor.  From there I am assuming also that these articles are in [content boxes](https://help.exacttarget.com/sv/documentation/exacttarget/content/email_overview/content_boxes/) and HOPEFULLY each 'article' is in a single content box.

If so, then your best bet is to go to the HTML tab on this box and copy that code there and have this inserted onto your company blog (or website if you do not have a blog). Your network admin or website designer will likely know the best way to insert these snippets of code to fit the layout and navigation of the site.

If your message is not personalized, or if so you mdke a generic recipient in your list, you may be able to use the 'view as webpage' link to get the source code.  Not sure if those links expire after X days or something though.I have never tried this or tested, but on most email sends there is a "view as webpage" link, maybe try taking one of these links and either hosting on your blog/site or using that link as a reference for your customers.

Using a PDF or screen shots is far from optimal as the content becomes an image and loses a lot of value.

Hope this helps.